# When to use the by keyword instead of the = operator?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are many places in the Android development documentation that use Kotlin delegates, but I don't quite understand the following example:

```kotlin
val uiState by viewModel.userFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

I looked at the `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` function

```kotlin
@ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi
@Composable
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
    initialValue: T,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
): State<T> {
    return produceState(initialValue, this, lifecycle, minActiveState, context) {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(minActiveState) {
            if (context == EmptyCoroutineContext) {
                this@collectAsStateWithLifecycle.collect { this@produceState.value = it }
            } else withContext(context) {
                this@collectAsStateWithLifecycle.collect { this@produceState.value = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this function I don't see anything related to the delegate, what am I missing?

When I use the `=` operator to define `uiState`, the type of `uiState` is `Sate<List<User>>`, and when using `by`, the type is `List<User>`. But I don't know what's the rationale.

If you don't read the documentation, can you tell me how to see from the source code that the `by` keyword must be used to define a variable?

Comment: The `State` type has an extension operator function, [`getValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State#(androidx.compose.runtime.State).getValue(kotlin.Any,kotlin.reflect.KProperty)), which allows it to be used as a delegate.

Comment: @Slaw You're right, it's the `State` that has to do with the delegate, not the `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` function

Answer (score 1):

It returns a State. State is a type that can optionally be used as a delegate. Any type that has the appropriate `getValue` operator function available can be used as a property delegate. Using it as a delegate is optional. It’s still a type that can be referenced like any other, and therefore assigned to a `val` with `=`.

You wouldn’t see anything about that in this function you posted. The ability to use it as a delegate is defined by the applicable operator function on the State type (it’s an extension function).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. use `by` can get `State.Value`, use `=` get `State`.